# How can I make abilities from custom classes in PCGen show on my D&D 3.5e character sheet?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pcgen

I feel like I am missing a step.

I take the code for a **wild mage** prestige class from a site (I dont know if  I am allowed to write the exact site here).

I put the data/code of the class in the `customclasses.lst` file, then I put data in the `customabilities.lst` and `customabilitycategories.lst`.

Although I see the prestige class and prerequisites on my pcgen screen and the advancement of spells , hit points, saves etc works just fine, the specical abilities of the class don't show on the character sheet.